# Why is there still a page from the private beta in the help center?

Tags: bug, help-center

I was surfing the help center and found this link on [how to ask questions in the private beta](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta).

Now I see how the points made in that post could still apply to the current public beta but, shouldn't we rename it into "How to ask questions in public beta"? Maybe there's another page suited for SE public betas and if so, should we switch to it?

<sup>Disclaimer: The tag [bug](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) is used as in "unexpected behaviour", I'm not saying this is a huge problem or anything :)</sup>

Comment: Because we never delete them. Every site has one, even sites that never went through the A51 process. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, this page is misleading. However, this issue is not uniquely relevant to Interpersonal Skills (for example, it was recently raised on [another site](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-help-page) as well). As is often the case with these types of issues, there is already a discussion about it on the [network-wide Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre) with no response from anyone with authority. It would seem that it is not considered significant enough to warrant a response, or there has simply not been enough attention/activity there. (Note that as of this writing the question there has a score of 34/0 and the answer has a score of 10/0, so no one actually disagrees.)

Perhaps a way to rejuvenate interest in this issue would be to post an answer there or add votes to the question and answer there to show that more people acknowledge this issue. Of course, there is never a guarantee that the powers-that-be will do anything about it, but it is more likely for the issue to be addressed as a network-wide issue than as an issue for one (small) site.